# How do I handle negative numbers in a PEG grammar?

Tags: python, parsing, peg, tatsu

I'm trying to write a simple int expression parser using [tatsu](http://tatsu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), a PEG-based Python parser generator. Here is my code:

```
import tatsu

grammar = r'''
    start = expression $ ;
    expression = add | sub | term ;
    add = expression '+' term ;
    sub = expression '-' term ;
    term = mul | div | number ;
    mul = term '*' number ;
    div = term '/' number ;
    number = [ '-' ] /\d+/ ;
'''
parser = tatsu.compile(grammar)
print(parser.parse('2-1'))
```

The output of this program is `['-', '1']` instead of the expected `['2', '-', '1']`.

I get the correct output if I either:

- Remove support for unary minus, i.e. change the last rule to `number = /\d+/ ;`
- Remove the term, mul and div rules, and support only addition and subtraction
- Replace the second rule with `expresssion = add | sub | mul | div | number ;`

The last option actually works without leaving any feature out, but I don't understand why it works. What is going on?

**EDIT**: If I just flip the add/sub/mul/div rules to get rid of left recursion, it also works. But then evaluating the expressions becomes a problem, since the parse tree is flipped. (`3-2-1` becomes `3-(2-1)`)

Comment: Most programming language grammars I've seen don't actually make the negative sign part of the number - it's just parsed as a unary minus operator applied to a positive number literal.

Comment: Have you tried eliminating left recursion from your grammar? The tatsu docs say left recursion support is experimental.

Comment: Looks like it works without left recursion, but then I lose left associativity. So this is just a bug in Tatsu?

Comment: I have much the same problem. I'd love to know why the first part (2) is disappearing from the AST.

Answer (score 1):

There are left recursion cases that TatSu doesn't handle, and work on fixing that is currently on hold.

You can use left/right [join/gather operators](https://tatsu.readthedocs.io/en/stable/syntax.html#op-e) to control the associativity of parsed expressions in a non-left-recursive grammar.